# Spring Cloud Data Flow UI - Remove Platform Properties

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a task deployed to a Spring Cloud Data Flow server using the UI.
I execute the task a couple of times, each time adding a new platform property through the Parameters box so its content looks like this before I launch the task for the second time:

```
app.param1=a
app.param2=b
```

For the third execution of the same task, I would like to remove the platform parameters. I try to do this by editing the content of the Parameters box so it is empty before I launch the task. However, on checking the third execution details, I find that the platform parameters have been retained:

[Third task execution information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXdDS.png)

My question is, is it possible to remove parameters (platform properties) from such a task using this UI?